# How to prevent IME input from switching when showing popups?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, ime

In my application, we use [Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.8) as containers, then we make customized [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow?view=netframework-4.8).

I need to show a popup with search textbox on it. Whenever I show this popup, my IME input would switch from Chinese/Japanese to English Mode. Based on articles like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh994466(v=vs.85)), input context should be either per user or per thread, why would my input change within my same app? (I am testing on Windows 10)

I have tried to keep the main app active by doing this, this would prevent the input from switching, BUT then my search box will not get keyboard input anymore when I show it, so I cannot use this method:

```
       protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) {
            switch(m.Msg) {
                case (int)WM.ACTIVATE:
                    if(m.WParam.ToInt64() == 1) {
                        UserMethods.SetActiveWindow(PopupOwner.Handle);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

It seems like the input switches as my active window changes.  But my search box needs to grab keyboard, so I believe I have no chioce but to change the active window.

I have also tried to create my own [input context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/imm/nf-imm-immcreatecontext), override CanEnableIme, and set ImeMode, none of these works perfectly, I can explain the details if that helps.

Note: my search box is a customized text editor, not the form textbox control; I made it handle IME input by processing system messages like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/processing-the-wm-ime-composition-message), but I am not modifying the input context, only reading from it.

How do I keep IME input mode stays the same when I change active window?

Comment: Can you make sure the main app and the popup box are in the same thread? Check it with `GetWindowThreadProcessId` return value.

Comment: Thank you @DrakeWu-MSFT, confirmed that they are on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why would my input switches within my app.

But to keep the IME mode stays the same after showing the popup with searchbox, I trap the IME status before the popup window gets activated, and after it's activated, I modify the IME status.  Something like this:

```
var imeOpened = false;
//get ime status
var hImc = ImmGetContext(popup.handle);
if(hImc != IntPtr.Zero) {
  imeOpened = ImmGetOpenStatus(hImc);
}

Showpopup();

//open ime if it was opened
if(hImc != IntPtr.Zero) {
  if(imeOpened) ImmSetOpenStatus(hImc, true);
  ImmReleaseContext(popup.handle, hImc);
}
```

In my app I have a disposable trapper, which make this a lot cleaner:

`using(TrapOpenedIme(popup.handle)) Showpopup()`

NOTE: `ImmSetConversionStatus` and `ImmGetConversionStatus` didn't work for me.

It's a hacky fix, but better than nothing :(